# Finding a function with some properties

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am trying to solve the following problem which stipulates certain conditions on the target function $f$. In other words, I want to find a non-constant function $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ such that

$$
1) \ \text{ The derivative } f':\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ is an even function } \\
2) \ f(z_1) \cdot f(z_2) \ldots f(z_n)= b_0+ \sum_{k} b_k \cdot f(a_{k1}z_1+\ldots+a_{kn}z_n),
$$
where $a_{k,i}, b_0$ are some real numbers. The second condition states that the product of the functions can be written as linear combination of the function whose arguments are again linear combinations of the original arguments. Does there exist any such function satisfying these conditions?

My attempt: The closest I could think  of is that $f$ is a shifted $\sin$ function, i.e, $f(z)=\frac{1+\sin z}{2}$. Clearly the derivative is an even function. But the product $f(z_1) \cdot f(z_2) \ldots f(z_n)$ can be written as linear combination of $\sin$ functions only if $n$ is odd. It fails for $n$ even.

Another function I have in mind is $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ but I an unable to verify if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that such a function exists (I suppose that you want (2) to be true for all $n$). Take $n=2$, and $z_1=z_2=z$. Then you have 
$$f(z)^2=\sum b_k f(c_kz)$$
with $c_k=a_{k,1}+a_{k,2}$. One compute the derivative

$$2f^{\prime}(z)f(z)=\sum b_k c_k f^{\prime}(c_k z)$$
Now replace $z$ by $-z$. As $f^{\prime}$ is even, you get that $2f^{\prime}(z)f(-z)=2f^{\prime}(z)f(z)$.

Hence we get that $2f^{\prime}(z)(f(z)-f(-z))=0$. Now if $g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)$, we have that $g^{\prime}(z)=f^{\prime}(z)+f^{\prime}(-z)=2f^{\prime}(z)$. Hence $g^{\prime}(z)g(z)=0$, $g(z)^2$ is a constant, and as $g(0)=0$, $g=0$. This means that $f$ is even, and then $f^ {\prime}$ is odd. But as $f^{\prime}$  is also even, we have $f^{\prime}=0$, and $f$ is constant.

Comment: Would the answer be the same if the second condition needs to hold only "almost everywhere"? The reason this is important is because the variables $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are actually some continuous random variables.

Comment: Not sure that I understand well your question, but as your function $f$ is continuous, an equality almost everywhere imply an equality everywhere.

Comment: What I meant to say is that in the above analysis $z_1=z_2=z$ is used to arrive at a contradiction. So what if such cases which cause problems are only of measure zero?

Comment: See my comment above: Suppose (2) is  true almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$; then as the function $f$ is continuous, this equality is true everywhere. So it has to be true when $z_1=z_2=z$ (when $n=2$).

Comment: How do you conclude that from (2) being equal almost everywhere that the "equality" in the above comment is true everywhere? Can you number the equations in your answer so that I can understand which equality you are talking about?

Comment: The equality (2) is your second condition. Put $g(z_1,\cdots ,z_n)=f(z_1)\cdots f(z_n)-\sum_b_kf(a_{k,1} z_1+\cdots+a_{k,n}z_n)$. Then $g$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $g$ is $0$ almost everywhere.if $g$ is not $0$ at some point $u$, by continuity, it is not zero on a small ball centered in  $u$. But the measure of a such a ball is $>0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I see. Effectively the punchline is continuity renders almost everywhere to everywhere, from where your above analysis carries over.